# Most performant KNN method in postgis (<->, <<->>, st_distance)

Tags: postgis, performance, spatial-index, st-distance

My question is about the fastest way to order query results by approximate distance. I've seen conflicting information about this.

My data are lat/lng points stored using WGS84 (SRID 4326).

The general query is simple enough

```sql
select * from table where [condition]
order by [distance function]
```

However, I'm not sure which of the following performs best:

```sql
st_distance(geom, st_setsrid(st_point(:lng, :lat), 4326));

geom <<->> st_setsrid(st_point(:lng, :lat), 4326));

geom <-> st_setsrid(st_point(:lng, :lat), 4326));

geom <#> st_setsrid(st_point(:lng, :lat), 4326));
```

I also understand that each of these can be sped up with different indexes, but I have trouble translating that in actual performance differences. For example, the docs don't mention anything about indexing regarding `st_distance`. Some answers on SE say that casting to geography speeds up `st_distance`. Furthermore, while `<#>` can use any spatial index, `<->` will only make use of a 2D GiST index, and `<<->>` will only make use of a n-d GiST index.

Does that make `<#>` potentially the fastest?

Comment: note that *<#>* gets distances between the bounding boxes, *<<->>* between bounding box centroids. while possibly fast, those are only approximations. note also: all KNNs do **only** use indexes when compared to a **constant** geometry, as stated in the docs.

Comment: Thanks! So for points I'm guessing `<->` is more precise than `<#>` but performance-wise they are the same? Also is there any difference in performance (or anything else) between `<<->>` and `<->` when used on 2D points?

Comment: Bounding box of a point is a point so it is precise.

Comment: D'oh!. So for points they are equivalent. What about the 2D vs n-D operator when dealing with 2D points?

Comment: You should be careful when calculating distances with lat lon coordinate systems as wgs84, because the distance value depends on the latitude. You should cast to geography not because of performance but to get correct results.

Comment: Is that true even when using `<->`?

Comment: sort of, it will return distance in degrees, which are *per se* not wrong. but pretty useless. and calculating meters from these then is what you have to be careful with. using *geography* type (on spheroid) is pretty much the most precise way to get the distance in meters. the KNNs will calculate meters on a sphere I think, when used on *geography*, being slightly inaccurate compared to true sphereoid distance